# NGINX+Windows how to serve a static html file (100kb) to 10k concurrent users

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2008-r2, load-balancing

This is the NGINX config file:

```
            gzip                  on;
            gzip_disable    "MSIE [1-6]\.";
            gzip_vary          on;
            gzip_proxied    any;
            open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s; 
            open_file_cache_valid 30s; 
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors on;
            access_log off;
            sendfile on;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on; 
            keepalive_timeout 0;
            reset_timedout_connection on;
            client_body_timeout 10;

            ...

            events {
               worker_connections  4000;
            }
            worker_processes  4;
```

The problem is that many users cannot get the file (cannot connect/timeout)
The file is a push message, to an desktop app.

So, I have two questions:
 1. Anyone knows the maximum "worker_connections" that ningx supports on Windows 2008 R2?
 2. Do I need to change something in Windows Registery, I cannot find what to change, and the exact numbers.

I don't want to be off-topic, but just to tell the background. Today I am serving the file using Amazon S3, and it cost almost $1000 per month. I have a dedicated server, so I want to save the $$$, and serve the file myself. If you know about other cheaper alternative to S3, you can comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using nginx on Windows? Why not nginx on Linux or IIS on Windows?

Comment: There are many features to use NGINX. (reverse_proxy, multi HTTPS urls on same IP, performance, and more)

Comment: Those features are available on Windows. What I'm asking isn't "why nginx?" it's "why nginx **on Windows**?" This isn't a common setup. People don't typically run applications designed for *nix and ported to Windows in production networks.

Comment: Soon or later I will move to Linux, and I want the transfer to be easy. The only reason I am using Windows is to server one old ASP Classic site. Do you believe that the performance of IIS on windows, will be better that the performance of NGINX?

Comment: Performance rarely is a product of the web server unless you're in extremely high-volume scenarios. Based on the question, I would doubt you're there. And yes, IIS can perform well. This website is run on IIS and MS SQL Server, for example.

Comment: Before I move to IIS, I cannot find any evidence, that IIS can server 10K simultaneous requests.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13987/discussion-between-amina-and-mdmarra)

Comment: The entire Stack Exchange network runs on it. What more evidence do you need?

Comment: @Amina: You appear to have evidence that nginx on windows on your server can't manage it why not just suck it and see the way yo have done with nginx?

Comment: Yes, on my server it's not work. Some om my users cannot connect or get a connection timeout error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I moved to IIS on my windows.. Now I can serve 10K+ users per seconds. it's not a problem any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, nginx has [significant limitations](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html):

- You can only have 1024 `worker_connections`. Any higher number will be ignored. And even if you start more than one, only one worker will actually do any work.
- nginx can only use `select()`; there is no high-performance event handler.

These are the reasons why using nginx on Windows for high performance, high scalability environments is a bad idea.

Switch to nginx on a non-Windows operating system as soon as possible.